# mysql error code 1054: Unknown column "author" in the field

Tags: sql, mysql, node.js, query-error

I have query which is giving me an error Code: 1054. Unknown column  'author_name' or sometime it says "operand should contain 1 column"

```
SELECT DISTINCT meet_id, hh, ha, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN flag = 1 THEN author_name ELSE NULL END SEPARATOR ', ') AS flagged_presenters, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN flag <> 1 THEN author_name ELSE NULL END SEPARATOR ', ') AS non_flagged_presenter, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS author_name 
FROM meet.inv, abs.inv 
WHERE meet_id = web_id 
GROUP BY meet_id, hh, ha;
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried putting `GROUP_CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS author_name` before the rest of the `GROUP_CONCAT()`? The script can't know, what `author_name` is before it has been defined.